# how get the content of an IEDboxEditor

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get the content of an Edit Control box and use it as a char[] or a char* , it's defined as :

```
 CString m_captureFile;
```

I tried to define a getter :

```
 CString CDecklinkCaptureDlg::getFilepath(){
return m_captureFile;
 }
```

and than

```
strcpy((char*)filep, getFilepath());
```

this didn't work ? any idea . 
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc.aspx) reference.

Try:

```
strcpy((char*)filep, (LPCTSTR)getFilepath());
```

Comment: is filep `char*` or `char []` type?